# Raw SQL statement invalid

Tags: sql, postgresql, pg

If this query would be done in Rails ORM, it would look like

```
ids = User.find(user_id).conversations.pluck(:id)
UserMessage.where("'conversation'.'id' IN (?)", ids)
```

My models are:

```
class User
  has_many :conversations, through: :user_conversations
end

class UserMessage
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :conversation
end
```

In raw SQL:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(
%( SELECT "user_messages".*,
    ( SELECT array_agg(t) 
      FROM (
      SELECT "conversations"."id"
      FROM "conversations"
      INNER JOIN "users_conversations" ON "conversations"."id" = "users_conversations"."conversation_id"
      WHERE "users_conversations"."user_id" = 'f044e064-0b6f-4371-91aa-3c03e31c8ad8'
     ) t
      ) AS this_user_conversations
   FROM "user_messages"
   WHERE "user_messages"."conversation_id" IN (this_user_conversations)))
```

this gives

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "this_user_conversations" does not exist
LINE 11: WHERE "user_messages"."conversation_id" IN (this_user_conver...
```

But well as far as I understand, this query defines this value with AS statement.

Comment: what is the result you want to achieve? maybe it can easier be accomplished with AR

Comment: @TheCha͢mp, no, this is just step where I stuck, in the end it should be processed as json, which is much faster than in ruby layer

Comment: also, does the user have many messages and does the message belong to the user?

Comment: can you include your full relations?

Comment: Why the complication of the subquery? Can be simply this: http://pastie.org/10858092

Comment: You are not assigining this_user_conversations to the user_messages but to the array_agg.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, because basically I don't want this user's messages, I want messages leaved by all other users in  conversations this user participates

Comment: I have a strong feeling that this can be done with another join. But I don't have a dataset to play with, and I'm too lazy to create one. BTW, I don't see where you exclude this user's messages from the resultset? You get his messages along with the others'.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, thanks, I refactored your query a little bit and now it outputs what I want.

Answer (score 0):

The `where` clause happens before the `select` list so it can't see the subquery. An alternative:

```
select
    um.*, tuc.this_user_conversations
from
    "user_messages" um
    inner join
    (
        select array_agg(c."id") as this_user_conversations
        from
            "conversations" c
            inner join
            "users_conversations" uc on c."id" = uc."conversation_id"
        where uc."user_id" = 'f044e064-0b6f-4371-91aa-3c03e31c8ad8'
    ) tuc on um."conversation_id" = any (tuc.this_user_conversations)
```

Comment: Your query is not equivalent. For one thing, it returns more data than needed. User is ultimately interested in user messages. Also, is it just me or you don't **need** this whole subquery piece?

Comment: Even if you do decide to go with the subquery for whatever reason, you certainly don't need to join conversations. `conversation_id` is already in user_conversations.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Do you mean it returns more rows or more columns? To have the aggregated array without the subquery it would be necessary to `group by` some column(s) from `user_messages`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: BTW why don't you post your answer?

Comment: I meant more columns.